# Javascript: Comparing two identical object literals

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure I figured this out before, but can't remember why this resolves to false. Can someone explain why?

```
if ({foo: 'bar'} === {foo: 'bar'}) {
  console.log("Strictly Equal");
} else {
  console.log("Not Equal");
}
```

I also tried == but it still has the two object literals as not equal.

Thanks

Comment: Please note, I'm voting to move this to SO. This isn't really a P.SE question. But, I think it fits on SO. Hence, I'm also giving a quick answer ...

Comment: @svidgen you might be interested in recent meta discussion: [Should I answer a question which belongs on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8069/31260)

Comment: @gnat Indeed. Didn't realize there was a consensus on this particular situation!

Comment: Sorry. About post to wrong site. My brain always goes code question = programmers, generic tech question = stackexchange.

Comment: Oh, not being snide or anything, but for the record I did look for what kind of question to post, and found this: "Programmers Stack Exchange ... who are interested in getting expert answers on conceptual questions about software development." off the Tour. I figured the question would fall under conceptual there because I was trying to remember the concepts behind why the code wasn't resolving to true. I thought there used to be a box that went straight to a detailed breakdown of what to post, but I don't see it anymore.

Comment: @BrianChandler "How does JavaScript handle object comparisons" might be on-topic for P.SE. But, "This object comparison isn't working, why not?" is almost undoubtedly Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` and `===` don't perform deep comparisons. They'll perform value comparisons for value types. But, objects are compared as references. And the objects in your comparison aren't the *same object*; they simply happen to be identical.

Comment: That's right! I totally forgot == and === only compare values. The references would be different so it would resolve as false. Thanks. It was irritating the heck out of me and when I googled around I couldn't find a good example similar (because I wasn't sure quite what to search for.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a different object. The string representation is the same though so you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify to convert the unique objects into a string. Then compare the strings and they will match.